# What will I need to start developing for iPhones?

Tags: iphone, delphi

I currently have Delphi 2010 and have just recently got an iPhone (5 days ago) which is my first ever venture into the Mac world. I absolutely love it btw - it has changed my life already.

If this should be posted somewhere else then I apologise and will do what is required to keep this question open, as I really need advice from you guys...

My Question/s

I want to begin developing for the iPhone but I am not sure where to begin and what I would need, ok I know that I would definitely need Delphi XE2! so that is one prerequisite and as mentioned above I already have an iPhone but what else would I need?

Would I actually need a physical Mac machine? and a developers account? I have looked on the Apple site and believe that I can sign up for one for free yet I have also read that it would cost $99 per year.

It would be ideal for someone here that already develops for iPhones to list all the prerequisites that I would need to begin this. I think this will be an expensive foray so I really want to get things right in my mind before I totally commit and invest real hard time and money that could lead me to go more grey ;) I have 3 grey hairs atm and I really want to try and minimise that!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginning iPhone Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885198/beginning-iphone-development), and a gazillion other such topics on this site. Please use the search box.

Comment: @Perception this is not really a duplicate, that question is 3 years old, and this is related to Delphi...

Comment: @Shamballa if you want to have a pretty steady development, what you need is: a Mac, XCode, and patience, everything else will give you a lot of headaches, just my $0.02

Comment: Delphi XE2 is by no means a requirement for iPhone development.

Comment: You should probably change your title to reflect the Delphi angle. Mind you, I linked one of about 10 pages of results that come up when you search 'begin iphone development', so the age of the one I linked is hardly relevant.

Comment: Well, you could very well consider a language other than Delphi.

Comment: @Perception there's a delphi tag there...

Comment: @Perception, the tags specifically indicate delphi. I don't see an edit that would have added it after the fact.

Comment: @ceeejayoz, the question was specifically tagged `delphi`. In order to do iPhone development **in Delphi**, you indeed require XE2. (Note I emphasized **Delphi**; the question was not tagged `freepascal`.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - That is something I will definitely look into

Comment: @DorinDuminica - I have a lot of patience (which thankfully is free)! I think I will start looking out for a second hand Mac (for now) but do you know what OS it would need at minimum for iPhone development? I am so out of touch with all this Mac stuff, it's quite scary...

Comment: @Shamballa sorry, I don't do OSX/iOS stuff, but I think you need at least Snow Leopard, but ask David Heffernan, he knows better than I do.

Comment: @Dorin No I don't. I know nothing at all about Apple stuff. What I do know is that developing on Windows and then exporting to a Mac and then compiling with FPC and then running on iOS is not a slick way to develop, no matter how well you know the delphi language. Whether using objective c and xcode is less painful is also moot.

Comment: @David OK, so, I have bad info, I thought you own and develop for Apple platforms... my bad...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [FireMonkey Development Setup for iOS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Development_Setup_for_iOS) spells things out pretty well. You obviously need a Mac in order to develop for iOS or OS X; you can compile OS X applications in the XE2 IDE, but you can't run them to test or debug without a Mac.

iOS development requires a Mac, as it requires XCode (which is Mac only); it also requires the Free Pascal compiler and some of the units it provides for iOS. You also require the Apple developer's account you mention (and indeed, it costs $99.00 a year).

Comment: Thank you, this indeed does explain everything I need to know.

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://sourceitsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/08/delphi-for-ios.html) discusses how to use Delphi XE2 for iOS development.

You can do the development in Delphi XE2, but you will need Xcode, a Mac, and a paid developer account to test on a device and to deploy to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

-- Updated ---

So for your first you have to own an Mac machine then you will need the dev account to deploy to iPhone as it should be compiled over a Mac OS X and deployed over the app store.

I recomend you to try it before put it on production, try xcode to so you can see the main diferences.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, didnt noted that before answear

Comment: I will delete this part hope you guys understand